Can I use age as a time varying covariate in a Cox PH?
I am studying how long a rebel group leader remains in charge of a rebel group until they are forced to step down. I have leader-year data with the following variables:

groupid = unique ID number for each group
leaderid = unique ID number for each leader
tenure = time since a leader first gained power (a count starting at 0)
forcedexit = takes a value of 1 when a leader is forced to step down, 0 all other years
groupage = time since the group formed (a count starting at 0)

My dataset has one row for every year that a rebel group is active. The data look generally like this:
   groupid leaderid forcedexit tenure groupage
     <dbl>    <int>      <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     411        1          0      0        0
 2     411        1          0      1        1
 3     411        1          0      2        2
 4     411        2          1      0        3
 5     411        2          0      1        4
 6     411        2          0      2        5
 7     411        2          0      3        6
 8     411        3          0      0        7
 9     411        3          0      1        8
10     411        3          0      2        9

Note that a new leader can come into power in ways other than a forced exit, so a leader may leave office even when forcedexit = 0 (e.g., see leaderid = 3 in the above data).
I would like to test whether leaders are harder to remove in older groups. My instinct is to run a Cox PH model (I am using R):
mod <- coxph(Surv(tenure, forcedexit) ~ groupage, data = df)
If I run this, I get a negative and significant estimate for the coefficent on groupage, which aligns with my intuition. However, I am wary of this result for two reasons.
First, can I use groupage as a time-varying variable in a Cox PH? Most of the medical studies I've read using Cox PH use variables for age that don't change over time (e.g., age at the start of the trial). My groupage variable does change over time.
Second, I'm worried that something spurious is happening with the relationship between the groupage and tenure variables. Some values of tenure are not possible at certain values of groupage. For example, there can never be a tenure = 5 and a groupage = 0 because the group must exist for the leader to be in charge of it. Thus, higher values of groupage may occur alongside higher values of tenure mechanically. For leaders to have a large tenure, the groupage must be large as well.
Any thoughts on either of these issues would be appreciated.

First, your use of groupage as a predictor doesn't represent the age of the individual that is at risk of the event, which is the usual age covariate in a Cox model. From the perspective of the individual at risk of the event, groupage is an external covariate. From that perspective, I don't see a problem that "higher values of groupage may occur alongside higher values of tenure mechanically" any more than there would be in a Cox model with calendar year as a covariate.
Second, even in Cox models where age represents the age at study entry of the individual at risk, there's a simplification explained in Section 5 of the time dependence vignette of the R survival package:

If age is entered as a linear term in the model, then the effect of changing age can be ignored in a Cox model, due to the structure of the partial likelihood.

Although the age at study entry doesn't change over time, age is effectively increasing for each individual over time. In a Cox model with age modeled linearly, however, the net effect of increasing age cancels out.
There's absolutely no problem with having an age variable that is a time-varying covariate. That's necessary if age is modeled non-linearly:

However, if the effect of age on risk is non-linear, this cancellation does not occur.

The vignette continues to show how to extend a data set to include age over time when necessary. That's relatively simple when you have a discrete-time model.*
There are a couple of  things missing from your model, however,
One is the potential correlation of tenure durations among leaders within the same groupid. Some groups might have inherently more unstable leadership than others. That's similar to having different outcomes at different medical institutions. Robust cluster variances or frailty/random-effects modeling would be needed to deal with that.
Another is the way that group leadership changes. Being forced out is different from dying while in leadership or agreeing to a fixed term as leader. What you have might be better handled by a competing risks or other multi-state survival model.

*Instead of a Cox model, which is based on continuous time and typically has to use approximations to deal with tied event times, you might consider a "grouped proportional hazards" discrete-time model, a binomial regression with a complementary log-log link. Your data seem already to have the appropriate formatting.
